# How do I get all possible combinations of a partially encoded string where characters remain in same order?

Tags: python, combinations

Sorry for the sort of confusing title - I'm not really sure how to phrase this.

What I want is all combinations of the string "hello" where the characters are in same order, but some are encoded. For example, the result should include "%68ello", "h%65llo", "%68el%6co", "h%65%6c%6c%6f" and so on.

The result should be 2⁵ different combinations if I'm not mistaken.

If possible, I'd prefer a solution in Python.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem.  Wouldn't it be easer to decode encoded input and check if it equals "hello"?  Also, SO isn't a code-writing service.  Attempt to solve the problem yourself and post the code with a problem when you are stuck.  see the [help].

Comment: I can guide you in the general direction by saying itertools.permutations and chr() functions will be useful in your case

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Please see [How to Ask a Homework Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Simply dumping your assignment here is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably get good results with a recursive generator:

```
def encodedCombo(S):
    if not S : yield ""; return
    for ss in encodedCombo(S[1:]):
        yield f"%{ord(S[0]):x}"+ss
        yield S[0]+ss
```

output:

```
for ec in encodedCombo("hello"): print(ec)

%68%65%6c%6c%6f
h%65%6c%6c%6f
%68e%6c%6c%6f
he%6c%6c%6f
%68%65l%6c%6f
h%65l%6c%6f
%68el%6c%6f
hel%6c%6f
%68%65%6cl%6f
h%65%6cl%6f
%68e%6cl%6f
he%6cl%6f
%68%65ll%6f
h%65ll%6f
%68ell%6f
hell%6f
%68%65%6c%6co
h%65%6c%6co
%68e%6c%6co
he%6c%6co
%68%65l%6co
h%65l%6co
%68el%6co
hel%6co
%68%65%6clo
h%65%6clo
%68e%6clo
he%6clo
%68%65llo
h%65llo
%68ello
hello
```